# The distribution of fourier coefficients of a Rademacher sequence

Tags: statistics, fourier-analysis

Assume that $x$ is a Rademacher vector or sequence with $x_i\in \{-1,+1\},i=1,2,...,N$ and $\Pr(x_i=+1)=\Pr(x_i=-1)=0.5$. What's the distribution of $\text{fft}(x)$?

Is that a gaussian distribution? What's the mean and variance of it?

Comment: By CLT, for large prime $N$, $X_0\approx N(0,\sqrt N)$ and $X_k\approx N_{kr}(0,\sqrt{N/2})+i\cdot N_{ki}(0,\sqrt{N/2})$ for $k\in[N-1]$. The catch is that all normals $N_{nr}$ and $N_{ni}$ are intricately interdependent and I can't simplify description of this dependency.

Comment: Are there any references?

Comment: Googling "Random Fourier series" shows something related. The above follows immediately from expansion though.